# $mobile = table_phone(); is displayed immediately even without calling $mobile

Tags: php

can anyone explain me why is my function value shown on a page immediately even without putting `<?php echo $mobile; ?>`

I just type this part:

```
<?php $mobile = table_phone(); ?>
```

and phone number gets displayed, but not where I want it. Not where I call

```
<?php echo $mobile; ?>
```

I tried to use other function like `osc_user_phone_land()` which is part of the osclass core and that one is working fine, but calling for mobile_phone, which is actually part of the plugin is not working properly.

Any ideas? My coding knowledge is quite limited so it might be a super simple fix..

Here is the more of the code:

```
<div class="description-right">
     <?php 
        $mobile = '';      
        if($mobile == '') { $mobile = table_phone(); }      
        if($mobile == '') { $mobile = __('No phone number', 'OSCLASS'); }      
     ?> 
   <div class="mob-wrap">

     <div class="mob-top">
       <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><?php _e("Contact", 'OSCLASS'); ?>     </span>
     </div>

     <div class="mobile-show" rel="<?php echo $mobile; ?>">
      <span>
          <?php 
            if(strlen($mobile) > 3 and $mobile <> __('No phone number', 'OSCLASS')) {
              echo substr($mobile, 0, strlen($mobile) - 3) . 'XXX'; 
            } else {
              echo $mobile;
            }
          ?>
      </span>
     </div>     

   </div>
```

function from helper.php

```
<?php
function get_realestate_attributes(){
    $locale = osc_current_user_locale();
    $return = array('attributes','other_attributes','special','lang','tel_num');
    $detail = ModelRealEstate::newInstance()->getAttributes( osc_item_id() );
    $keys = array_keys($detail) ;
    if(count($keys) == 1 && $keys[0] == 'locale' && is_null($detail[0]['locale']) ){
        // nothing to do
        return false;
    } 

    if(@@$detail['locale'][$locale]['s_number'] != "") {
        $return['tel_num']['year'] = array(
                 'label' =>__('Telephone number', 'realestate_attributes')
                ,'value' => @@$detail['locale'][$locale]['s_number']
            );
    }
    return $return;
}


function table_phone(){ 
    $detail = get_realestate_attributes();
    if($detail['tel_num']){
    ?>     
        <span>
        <?php
            foreach($detail['tel_num'] as $item){
                echo ''.$item['value'].'';
            } 
        ?>
        </span>

    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say your not giving us alot to work with. But is there a return in table_phone()

Comment: is it possible your function has en echo value within it?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `table_phone()` method like this :

```
function table_phone(){ 
    $detail = get_realestate_attributes();
    $result = '';

    if($detail['tel_num']) {
       foreach($detail['tel_num'] as $item){
            $result .= $item['value'];
        } 
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Now you can do `$mobile = tab_phone();`, you'll not have any output.
And when you want display it, use `echo $mobile`.

Because I've removed the `<span>` in your method, you can juste add it manually like :

```
<span><?php echo $mobile; ?></span>
```

If you cannot change the method, use a closure like the following :

```
if($mobile == '') { 
    $mobile = function() { 
        table_phone(); 
    };
}
```

And everywhere you call `$mobile`, use :

```
<?php $mobile(); ?> // Result is displayed
```

Comment: Hi chalasr, many thanks for your help, 1st option works great... You have made my day!

Comment: You're welcome @Magnettoo. Don't forget to mark your question as answered when is it :)